# How do you deal with loot in an RPG where all mosters drop their full inventory?

Tags: architecture, rpg, inventory

I currently have a system where both players and monsters in an RPG use equipment. This means that when an enemy is killed, **I can technically drop everything they have**. These are armor and weapons that players may choose to equip. This is fun for the first 5 times this happens(when the player is missing some equipment), then the inventory gets crowded with junk, and it's hard to figure out what's valuable and what's not. Most of the NPCs will lag behind player in terms of gear with the exception of bosses, who will have very good gear.

I've seen suggestions of using a **"junk bag"**, where looted white/ gray equipment goes. Junk bag can be sold with one click.

I can think of two old school MMORPGs that had near full loot: Shadowbane and ultima Online. Both of these used disposable equipment that was easy to craft or "farm" from NPCs.

Recently the age of decadence, a PC RPG had a good full looting system where **equipment could be broken down** to get iron ingots and such and used in crafting. However, that game only has less than 100 enemies to kill and loot during the entire game, and had weight limit.

In my game there would be hundreds of enemies to kill in rapid succession, maybe 2-3 kills per minute. Another option is to abandon the full looting idea and only "drop greens, blue and purple items if the enemy had them.

In other words, how do you use or get rid of unwanted items when there is a lot of junk loot?

Comment: "Fun" is subjective, please describe what you want in technical terms.

Comment: Your suggestion sounds interesting. I would suggest just going with it, and asking your real users what they think later.

Comment: I'm also interested in this question. Tried to edit the question to make it less subjective.